# Pyusb Read error: NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

Tags: python, usb, pyusb

When I run the following :

```
if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):
```

I get an input output error:
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

Note:

- Device: Simple Optical Mouse
- OS: Windows
- Python version: 3.7

Full Code (if needed):

```
import usb.core

vid = 0x1C4
pid = 0x002

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=vid, idProduct=pid)


interface_0 = dev[0].interfaces()[0]
ep = interface_0.endpoints()[0]
intf_num = interface_0.bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

dev.set_configuration()
eaddr = ep.bEndpointAddress

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0):      #Error
    print('123')
```

I could not find any working solution online. The one which I found suggested that I had the wrong driver, but the driver seems to be fine. I've also tried to use different usb devices and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

the is_kernel_driver_active() only works with linux

Comment: Yeah that seems to be it